# How better way to create a function to pass a JSON by serializer in django rest?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm studying django rest framework and would like the create a function. In this function, I need to pass a list in JSON and update by serializer.

For help I wrote a code example below.

Serialzer example:

```
class GarageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Garage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GarageSerializer
    model = Garage

class CarViewSet(RestrictedQuerysetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    model = Car
```

Well. I need to update a car list through the garage serializer. I'm thinking anything like this:

(example view)

```
class GarageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Garage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GarageSerializer
    model = Garage

    @action(detail=True, methods=['put'])
        def update_car(self, request):
            ...
            serializer = CarSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            ...
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Attempt 1:**

Searching and reading the doc, I tried this way:

```
        @action(methods=['put'], detail=False)
        def update_car(self, request, *args, **kwargs):     
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            serializer = CarSerializer(data=data, many=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

But I received this error:

```
non_field_errors:
["Expected a list of items but got type "dict"."]
```

**Attempt 2:**

With a @fxgx I tried too:

```
    def update_car(self, request):
        serializer = CarSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        validated_data = dict(list(serializer.validated_data.items()))
        queryset = Car.objects.update(**validated_data)
        return Response(CarSerializer(queryset, many=True).data)
```

But I received this error:

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DRF serializers do not support bulk updates, you must pass an object instance to serializer to update it. What you can do is serializing data using serializer, updating objects with validated data and then serializing objects again to get response data:

```
    class GarageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Garage.objects.all()
        serializer_class = GarageSerializer
        model = Garage

        @action(detail=False, methods=['put'])
        def update_car(self, request):
            ...
            # Use partial=True for partial updates.
            serializer = CarSerializer(data=request.data)

            # Validate data.
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

            # Get validated data in dictionary format.
            validated_data = dict(list(serializer.validated_data.items()))

            # Update objects
            quertset.update(**validated_data)

            ...
            return Response(CarSerializer(queryset, many=True).data)
```

Comment: Hey @fxgx. Thank you. I tried something like your help. I will test now and send feedback.

Comment: I has some doubts about your example... I update my question.

Comment: @JoeyFran you defined this view as detail, which means you are taking this action on a Garage object. Are you sure that you are giving right Garage id to your url ?

Comment: My url example `router.register(r"garage", GarageViewSet, base_name="garage")`. I'm did not giving the id to url, sorry. Giving a id I receive `update_car() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'`

Comment: Okay, let me ask that. Do you want to update all the cars or do you want to update all the cars that belongs to a Garage? If you want second one, please update the question and put your Garage and Car models there so that i can help.

Comment: The first case. In the future I will create a nested relationship in both.

Comment: @JoeyFran, then you don't need to use `detail=True`, i updated the answer.

Comment: Hey @fxgx. Thanx again. I change to "detail=false" and the error is now `'int' object is not iterable`. Did you see my function (attempt 2)? The line "quertset.update(**validated_data)" that you wrote works like my example (attempt 2)?